# Angular 2 multiselect dropdown in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have followed this in one of my machine. working fine.(In that machine I was having all of my imports in app module)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Then I have another machine where Each functionality is having different module. so i want to use it in my dashboard module. so tried importing it in my dashboard module, it throws an error, then I tried importing in my app module. still throwing an error, then tried at both the places, still throwing an error. what wrong am I doing?

Comment: Can you share your code where you are importing and also share the module architecture